# MongoExpress not reading login/password from .env file

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, mongo-express

I am using docker-compose where I set the environmental variables to be:

environment:

```
- ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME=${MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN}
- ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD=${MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD}
```

only when I do:

```
environment:
- ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_USERNAME="username"
- ME_CONFIG_BASICAUTH_PASSWORD="password"
```

it works there, but I want to make it so you can edit the credentials easily.

for some reason when i do the environmental variables for mongoDB it works:

```
environment:
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_ROOT_USER}
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD}
```

here is my env file

```
MONGO_ROOT_USER=admin
MONGO_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
MONGOEXPRESS_LOGIN=punkmeister
MONGOEXPRESS_PASSWORD=testingStuff
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you try to achieve, the question is not so clear. You can pass the env with docker-compose run -e DEBUG <service>.

Comment: @CyrilG. 

Sorry about the wording. I am trying to be able to create a web login for Mongo Express. I have created an env file with all my credentials. 

Whenever I try using the env file to correspond with the docker-composer, for some reason mongo express will not read the env file. I have to manually edit the docker-composer instead of the env file to edit the password.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
environment:
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
- MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

and your .env file

```
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=adminpassword
```

Comment: the root username and password works, however the mango express website authorization doesn't replace the credentials from the env file.

Thank you for your time.